# Открытие ссылки из WebView в новом активити с WebView

Tags: android, activity, webview, android-intent

В MainActivity есть WebView который открывает страничку. На страничке есть ссылки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать открытие этих ссылок в новом активити (WebViewActivity) с WebView.

Answer (score 2):

Юзайте свой `webViewClient` с перекрытым `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`. Должно получиться что-то типа

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), WebViewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("url", url);    
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если есть возможность, можно подробнее на примере?

Comment: @Mariner не совсем понял о каком примере речь?) Вроде бы как в ответе пример и есть

Comment: За пример спасибо) Буду разбираться, только начал) Но сильно пример мне ничего не говорит. Я смысл понял, а вот под своё не могу применить. Если вставить ваш ответ, то getContext(), WebViewActivity.class что то не нравиться Android студии. - Cannot resolve constructor "Intent(java.security.AccessControlContext, java.lang.Class<ru.test.test.WebViewActivity>